# Best way to password protect a folder?

Tags: php, vb.net, cgi

I am trying to create a similar way to Cpanel password protect directory, where a pop up comes out asking the user for a username and a password, but Cpanel way is amazing but my client doesn't know anything on how to do that, so i wanted to create a pop up msgbox informing the visitor to enter a user name and a password, and i totaly confused on how to create it, and which programming language support similar to CPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create .htaccess With basic authentication (running from web browser).
You must create users and password file. You may fing many maunals on web about it.
For example: http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/

Comment: There also is an online tool for generation of htaccess and htpasswd files: http://www.clockwatchers.com/htaccess_tool.html, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to protect the page with .htaccess.

There is a guide on how to do this [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/).